# average operation ARM NEON

Tags: arm, sse, simd, neon, intrinsics

I need to compute the same operation as the SSE one:

```
__m128i result1=_mm_avg_epu8 (upper, lower);
```

With NEON I do the following:

```
uint8x16_t result1=vhaddq_u8(upper, lower);
```

The results should be the same but with the SSE instruction I obtain:

```
91cb c895 aaa3 b0d4 cfc0 c1b0 aac7 b9b9
```

whereas with the NEON instruction I obtain:

```
91ca c894 a9a2 b0d3 cec0 c1af aac7 b8b8
```

I don't understand why the two results are different. Can you help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Neon "halving add" operation `vhadd` works like this:

```
A = (B + C) >> 1
```

whereas the SSE average intrinsic `_mm_avg_epu8` does this:

```
A = (B + C + 1) >> 1
```

In other words Neon does a *truncating* average with its "halving add" operation, whereas SSE correctly rounds the result.

Fortunately there is a Neon instruction which rounds in the same way as SSE's `_mm_avg_epu8` - it's called [vrhadd](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0348a/BABDFJCI.html) - Vector Rounding Halving Add.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I solved using vrhadd which does exactly the same as SSE Vr[i]:=(Va[i]+Vb[i]+1)>>1.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `vrhadd` [[1]](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/BABDFJCI.html) [[2]](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/ch05s126.html).

```
Vector rounding halving add: vrhadd -> Vr[i]:=(Va[i]+Vb[i]+1)>>1
```

Comment: Many NEON instructions feature Q and R flags, q for saturation and r for rounding.